# Fortran sqrt () error

Tags: fortran

I am very new in Fortran and I am stuck with the following program to find roots using quadratic equation.

It is showing the following error:

> d = sqrt(bsq \xE2\x80\x93 ac4)
>   1
>   Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

```
program quadratic
implicit none 
real :: a, b, c, root1, root2
real :: bsq, ac4, d 
print *, 'Please enter the coefficients a, b, and c as real numbers'
read *, a, b, c
bsq = b*b
ac4 = 4*a*c 
if ( bsq < ac4) then
d = sqrt(bsq – ac4)
root1 = (-b+d)/(2*a)
root2 = (-b+d)/(2*a)
print *, 'The real roots are ', root1, root2
else if ( root1==root2) then
root1 = root2
print *, 'There is one real root which is ', root1
else
print *, 'There are no real roots'
end if
end program quadratic
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a minus sign between `bsq` and `ac4`, not a dash. Look closely.

Minus sign: -
         Dash: –